# How generate Swagger file with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1 targeting .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core 2.2 projet that target .NET Framework 4.8
2. Follow 'Getting Started' to add Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

This give this repository :
https://github.com/Orwel/GenerateSwaggerFileWithDotnetFramewrok

3. Build
4. Go in the folder 'bin/net48'
5. Execute the command : `swagger tofile WebApplication1.exe v1`

That display the error :

```
A JSON parsing exception occurred in [.\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\net48\WebApplication1.exe]: * Line 1, Column 2 Syntax error: Malformed token
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in '.\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\net48\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the .\bin\Debug\net48\WebApplication1.json file specifying the appropriate framework.
```

This error is generally attributed when a .NET Core application loads a DLL targeting other runtime.
Maybe Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli cannot be used with .NET Framework API.

How generate Swagger file with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1 targeting .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: `ASP.NET Core 2.2 project that targets .NET Framework 4.8` I think that would not be a Core project

Comment: If there is also a WebApplication1.dll, what happens when the command is run with that dll?
I ran into that error when pointing to the exe, and a different one with the dll because the name parameter was wrong

Comment: The project target the classic .NET Framework, then the build don't generate {project's name}.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to generate the swagger file from a program external to the API.

I modified the api that generate the `swagger.json` file :

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "generate")
        {
            var json = webHost.GenerateSwagger("v1", null);
            File.WriteAllText("swagger.json", json);
        }
        else
        {
            webHost.Run();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    public static string GenerateSwagger(this IWebHost webhost, string docName, string basePath)
    {
        var sw = webhost.Services.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
        var doc = sw.GetSwagger(docName, null, basePath);

        using (var streamWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var writer = new OpenApiJsonWriter(streamWriter);
            doc.SerializeAsV3(writer);
            return streamWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I will accept answer will generate `swagger.json` without reference the api project.